# GCM Server application concept

Tags: gradle, server, google-cloud-messaging

Hey guys so after reading and spending a lot of time on the server application that implements XMPP , I still don't understand where does the server application resides if I actually do run the server on the internet ( not on my computer) .

I have already looked and managed to get this example to work on my computer:
https://github.com/googlesamples/friendlyping/tree/8b34acdcd63336e73ba77f0296c69ca43c63f6ca

but now I want to know how do I actually implement the server an actually environment? as the one in the example is just running the server through Android studio by Gradle.

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a read from the [Implementing an XMPP Connection Server](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs) docs:

> The CCS XMPP endpoint runs at gcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5235. When
>   testing functionality with non-production users, you should instead
>   connect to gcm-preprod.googleapis.com:5236 (note the different
>   hostname and port).
>
> Regular testing on preprod (a smaller environment where the latest CCS
>   builds run) is beneficial for isolating real users from test code.
>   Test devices and test code connecting to
>   gcm-preprod.googleapis.com:5236 should use a different GCM sender ID
>   to avoid any risks of sending test messages to production users or
>   sending upstream messages from production traffic over test
>   connections.
>
> The connection has two important requirements:
>
> You must initiate a Transport Layer Security (TLS) connection. Note
>   that CCS doesn't currently support the STARTTLS extension. CCS
>   requires a SASL PLAIN authentication mechanism using
>   @gcm.googleapis.com (GCM sender ID) and the Server
>   key as the password, where the sender ID and Server key are the values
>   you gathered when configuring your client app. See the client
>   documentation for your platform for information on obtaining these
>   credentials. If at any point the connection fails, you should
>   immediately reconnect. There is no need to back off after a disconnect
>   that happens after authentication.

Comment: thank you for the reply , what I meant was where can I run my server online ? for example I can put my website online on a hosting server , how can I do the same for my server application since I have to use Gradle commands to make it run ?

Comment: Are you trying to make your own GCM Server?

Comment: No , I'm making a server to connect to GCM ( I already succeeded thanks to the demo provided by google see the link I posted above).
but the server resides on my computer by using Android studio Gradle terminal . how can I put it online , on the internet ?